# screenOptions:{{tabBarHideonKeyboard: true}} not Working

Tags: react-native, tabbar, react-navigation-v6

When I am using custom tab bar through `tabBar` function `tabBarHideOnKeyboard` does not work but without `tabBar` function it works fine, any ideas on how I can make it work using `tabBar` function as well.

Comment: what Tab are you using? there are 3 tabs in `react-navigation`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @jted95 I am using bottom tab navigator

Answer (score 3):

Add `"softwareKeyboardLayoutMode": "pan"` in app.json file under "android" key and then restart your expo server with `expo start -c`

Comment: Gonna mess up your keyboardavoidingviews

Answer (score 2):

```
<Tab.Navigator
  tabBarOptions={{
    showLabel: false,
    keyboardHidesTabBar: true, // use this props to hide bottom tabs when keyboard shown
  }}
```

the docs says to use `tabBarHideOnKeyboard`, but not working at all.
then i found `keyboardHidesTabBar` and works like a charm

Comment: It's not working @Zacquio, I'm using tabBar custom component with  
**position: "absolute";**

Comment: screenOptions={{
        tabBarHideOnKeyboard: true}} is the how it is done now. " tabBarOptions={{" is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using a custom tab bar with v6 you can use

```
screenOptions={{
   tabBarHideOnKeyboard: true,
}}
```

But with a custom tab bar, you have to manage that yourself. The way I did it was to create a custom hook that tracks the keyboard's status and change the `tabBarStyle` according to that.

```
screenOptions={{
    tabBarStyle: { display: keyboardStatus ? 'none' : 'flex' },
  }}
```

where `keyboardStatus` is a hook that returns true or false using the `useLayoutEffect` hook from react and the [Keyboard.addListener()](https://reactnative.dev/docs/keyboard#addlistener) from react-native.

Answer (score 0):

You'll get the `tabBarHideOnKeyboard` from the props for the custom `tabBar`.

```js
tabBar={(props) => {
  return (
    <View>
      {props.state.routes.map((route, index) => {
        // You can replace Pressable and View with anything you like
        return (
          props.descriptors[route.key].options.tabBarHideOnKeyboard && (
            <Pressable>
              <View
                style={{
                  width: 200,
                  height: 200,
                  backgroundColor: "green",
                }}
              />
            </Pressable>
          )
        );
      })}
    </View>
  );
```

You can read more [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/)

Comment: Didn't worked..

Comment: what didn't work? did you get error? do you still get the tabBarHideOnKeyboard` value from if you follow some of my code?

Comment: I get the tabBarHideonKeyboard value true but still bottom tab bar doesn't hide when keyboard opens

Comment: @AdeelYousaf, how do you handle it? can you show me the code?

Comment: issue has been resolved, I added a keyboard listener and on keyboardopen changed the value of bottom to negative which worked for me, btw thanks a lot.

Comment: @AdeelYousaf no problem

Answer (score 0):

I was using my customTab as well. And after huge amount of search, solved the problem with the help of Keyboard event listeners.

This is the best solution, I've found so far.

Here's my solution:

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Keyboard, Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from "react-native"

export default function TabBar({ state, descriptors, navigation }) {
    // As default it should be visible
    const [visible, setVisible] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        const showSubscription = Keyboard.addListener("keyboardDidShow", () => {
            //Whenever keyboard did show make it don't visible
            setVisible(false);
        });
        const hideSubscription = Keyboard.addListener("keyboardDidHide", () => {
            setVisible(true);
        });

        return () => {
            showSubscription.remove();
            hideSubscription.remove();
        };
    }, []);

   //Return your whole container like so
   return visible && (
         <View>
             ...
         </View>
         )
```

`tabBarHideOnKeyboard` or `keyboardHidesTabBar` options didn't work for me.